# file .h not found xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I received an Xcode project from my friend, supposed to work successfully without error,

but when I run it for the first time, there is an error,

an import file in **PrefixHeader.pch** not found!

"'FAButton.h' file not found"

but the library is existing in the pod file

I tried to delete the pod file, and reinstall it from the command line,

but the error still appears.

[image]

I don't have a lot of knowledge about Xcode and swift,
I think there are some steps I should do when the run project for the first time,
but I don't know what is the problem

anyone can help me ??

Comment: Can you show your `Podfile` and the output of `pod install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you open the `.xcworkspace` file? You should open the `.xcworkspace` file not the `.xcodeproj` file